# If I enable state server, where does application state go?

Tags: iis, session-state, application-variables

Enabling a state server moves session state to the server instead of in-proc.
Does this also happen to application state? Or does it stay in-proc (and thus, un-shared)?

Comment: Most legacy articles on that topic was written in early 2000s for ASP.NET 1.x, so no doubt you have such questions. But take a look at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net and I believe all necessary details are there.

Comment: Different from the session state , application state is always stored in the server. The session state settings won’t affect where application state stores.

Comment: @LexLi Trying to find "application state" or "application variable" on the linked page yields no result.

Comment: @samwu Thanks. You're the only one here who actually answered the question.